# WSO2 API Manager 2.2.0 - How to enable grant_type=password for other tenant users?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I was using WSO2 API Manager 1.9.0.
Now trying to upgrade WSO2 API Manager 2.2.0.

But when I create a subscription using `grant_type=password` to generate token with other tenant users am getting error

> {"error_description":"Users in the tenant domain : taskforce.com do not have access to application testsubscriber_taskforce_PRODUCTION","error":"invalid_grant"}

The subscription from another tenant user abcd.com.

But this was working in WSO2 API Manager 1.9.0

Should I enable any configuration to get this functionality?

Comment: Try enabling 'SaaS App' in the `testsubscriber_taskforce_PRODUCTION` SP from management console.

Comment: I dont have any idea that how to enable SAAS app though management console for an API subscription. Do u have any reference link ? For every API i subscribe should i do this ?

Comment: Go to `/carbon` >> `Service Providers` >> Edit a Serivice Provider >> You'll see `SaaS Application` check box.